# Laravel: can't login after removing SESSION_DOMAIN from environment variable

Tags: php, laravel, session, session-cookies

In production environment, Session domain is set into .env file like this:
`SESSION_DOMAIN='example.com'`

Now, I need to deploy the same codebase into different subdomain, i.e: **staging.example.com**

If I remove the `SESSION_DOMAIN='example.com'` from .env file, all user wont be able to login anymore, because of session cookies from browser.

What is the solution now, if I dont want any interruption in the real user?

Comment: don't remove it... don't you explain why you want to remove it?

Comment: Maybe instead of deleting config you should change it to suit the new installation?

Comment: There are two server with same codebase. My automated script is checking the production server in every minutes. If the production server is down, I am pointing the domain to backup server. Here is the example:

1. Production server: example.com
2. Backup Server: backupexample.com

So, when example.com is down, I am just pointing the example.com to the backup server. make sense?